# Парсинг сайтов, не выдаёт href Данные

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Не могу разобраться, какие могут быть проблемы?
При попытке спарсить href на профиль и записать в блокнот, блокнот создается, но данных в нем нет.

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

persons_url_list = []

for i in range (10, 500, 20):
    url = f'https://rarible.com/explore/all/items?multiple=all&verified=false&platforms[]=RARIBLE&platforms[]=OPEN_SEA'

    q = requests.get(url)
    result = q.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
    persons = soup.find_all(class_='sc-bdvvtL sc-hUpaCq sc-jgrJph mluVk dqVzIo')

    for person in persons:
        person_page_url = person.get("href")
        persons_url_list.append(person_page_url)

with open('persons_url_list.txt', 'a') as file:
    for line in persons_url_list:
        file.write(f'{line}\n') ```
````

Comment: Вы парсите информацию  авторизированных пользователей?

Comment: Да, на каждой карточке есть ссылка на профиль пользователя. Вот их и нужно забрать

Comment: я имел ввиду вы видите эту информацию когда вы авторизированы или информация которую вы хотите спарсить видна не авторизированным пользователям?

Comment: Да, информация видна